# Collision that governs kinetic model of gas

Tags: physical-chemistry

From Atkins' Physical Chemistry 10th, it states that

> The kinetic model is based on three assumptions:
>
> 1. The gas consists of molecules of mass $m$ in ceaseless random motion obeying the laws of classical mechanics.
> 2. The size of the molecules is negligible, in the sense that their diameters are much smaller than the average distance travelled between collisions.
> 3. The molecules interact only through brief elastic collisions.

I quite can't get the second assumption. The intermolecular distance between the molecules are greater than the diameter of the molecules, so we can neglect the volume. Given Boyle's law apply (as omitting size and volume of molecules is a property that ideal gas has), there will be many molecules collide with the walls and the molecules will hit another molecules after its collision with wall (right?), thus the pressure of the system should be low. How often the collision of what kind happens under what condition?

If the separation doesn't result any influence on each molecule (because third assumption said elastic collision, so any interaction (hydrogen bonding, van der Waals, so on) higher than the collision energy should be omitted), will the collision come purely from their collision with walls, not collision between each molecule?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases) states also the assumption that

> The number of molecules is so large that statistical treatment can be applied.

Comment: What's the question, really? There can be no walls and even if there are, something like you imagine would invalidate model, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Mithoron The main question is what kind of collision in the kinetic model under the assumptions. If there's no walls, is it possible to relate the collision with Boyle's law?

Comment: The molecules interact only through brief elastic collisions *(with each other and perhaps with other stuff)*.

Comment: @Mithoron Interesting, so that brief collision is happened with high pressure?

Comment: In any pressure whatsoever - that how gas works! This theory is supposed to be somewhat realistic...

Comment: @Mithoron I didn't know the model can be thought to be simple like that. The book put the context in chapter of perfect gas so the book overstates the theory, I think. Thank you.

Comment: The key requirements are (1) thermal equilibrium (2) a continuous energy distribution (not discrete particle counts) and (3) negligible intermolecular energy. There is a lot of room between "enough particles" to satisfy these conditions and "high pressure". You can simply scale up the volume if you want to increase the number of particles and ensure smoother statistics.

Comment: The measured pressure of a gas in a vessel (ie the pressure the gas exerts on the walls of the vessel) can be calculated from the properties of the gas molecules (like their average momentum) assuming elastic collisions with the walls. in short, collisions of molecules with walls **is** the pressure.

Comment: So I've no idea where the "thus the pressure of the system should be low" comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There will be many molecules collide with the walls and the molecules will hit another molecules after its collision with wall (right?), thus the pressure of the system should be low. How often the collision of what kind happens under what condition?

The collision condition doesn't need to be strictly in Boyle's law condition, that the elastic collision is happened between anything and under any pressure condition. The requirement of large number of molecules but only collision interactions are applied implies that it is just not applicable to apply Boyle's law in kinetic model of gas.